# PIN diode - what setting to detect the frequency?

Tags: photodiode

My question regarding the use of the PIN photo diode, I could not understand what would be the best configuration using an integrator operational amplifier for frequency detection if it is the photo conductor or photovoltaic?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make an optical receiver or an RF detector? What frequency are you trying to detect, the carrier wave or a sub-carrier modulated onto the carrier? What's the frequency range of the signal you're trying to detect?

Comment: Also the photovoltaic mode circuit should have some connections to bias the non-inverting op-amp input to a fixed voltage. You might want to look for a better source to learn from than wherever you found these diagrams.